# Problem with date function in php

Tags: php

My friend is echoing the date using date(G:i:s) but the result getting displayed is neither the current system time nor the xampp server time (as he is using xampp).

so what is the possible reason for this problem and the solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How far out is the returned results? Is it out by a whole number of hours? If so, there is a timezone issue on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php, the function

`date_default_timezone_get()`

will return the currently configured timezone of the running script. If no timezone was set via either a runtime option or PHP INI file, it will return the UTC timezone. This will let you figure out what is going on.

To set the timezone to what you want, use

```
date_default_timezone_set()
```

Link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 0):

date('G:i:s') ?

Comment: I thought so too, but php should spit out a parse error, not an arbitrary date.

Comment: PHP assumes unrecognised tokens are strings in many cases. It's a legacy "feature" :)